# Failure to set APP_ENV to 'testing' for unit testing in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am using Laravel 5.5, phpunit 6.5.5 on Homestead-7 (I think).

I am trying this tutorial: https://laravel-news.com/your-first-laravel-application (And this should tell you a lot about my experience with the framework)

Testing fails (due to `TokenMismatchException`) and I have managed to track down the root cause to the `APP_ENV` variable being set to `local`, although I've tried many ways of setting it to `testing`.

At the end, what allowed me to overcome the problem was to set the variable like this:

```
APP_ENV=testing vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Then, the tests completed successfully.

My question is, what am I doing wrong? The above hack is obviously not the best way to do it. There must be a way to properly do this.

**Update**

Contents of `phpunit.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you set the variable like `APP_ENV=testing vendor/bin/phpunit`? I have the same (or similar) issue..

Comment: @greener Please see the answer by jdunk and my own answer at the bottom to find more about the proper way to set APP_ENV.

Answer (score 10):

From [the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/testing#environment):

> When running tests via `phpunit`, Laravel will automatically set the configuration environment to `testing` because of the environment variables defined in the `phpunit.xml` file.

...so I would bet that your `phpunit.xml` file is missing or misconfigured. It should be in your project's root directory and should contain the following:

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    ...
</php>
```

If you *do* have a `phpunit.xml` file in the right place and it *does* contain the part above, and it's *still* not working, then try clearing your config cache:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

If that still doesn't fix it, then I'd check for something odd with the `phpunit.xml` file, such as being misnamed or containing a syntax error.

And [here's a link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/laravel/v5.5.28/phpunit.xml) to the original `phpunit.xml` file, to help you restore it if needed.

Comment: I am aware of the documentation reference. My `phpunit.xml` is correct and at the correct location. I have tried clearing my config cache, again now. Not much syntax in `phpunit.xml`, hence I'm quite confident it's correct. For that matter, I've tried changing the `APP_ENV` in `.env` -no luck. Hence I resorted to the hack, which to my surprise worked.

Comment: @mirnis Can you share the contents of your `phpunit.xml` file?

Comment: Also, try restoring the original `phpunit.xml` file (link added in my answer), clear config again, and see if it works then.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, weekend happened. Contents of file shared above. I had already tried restoring the original file, I just did it again, I cleared config, it did not work.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks @jdunk! I had the issue for a week, was losing my mind. `php artisan config:clear` worked a treat, makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find the problem with my system. In my homestead box, I had included in `Homestead.yaml` setting of global environment variable APP_ENV:

```
variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
    - value: local
```

This was provided as an example in the instructions for Homestead set up. I followed that without realising what I was doing.

Setting again the variable through `.env` or `phpunit.xml` just did not work. I removed the definition from `Homestead.yaml` and it works as I would have expected.

Comment: ah yes, that would do it. As it says in a blue-backgrounded note at the top of the Laravel docs for Configuration "Any variable in your .env file can be overridden by external environment variables such as server-level or system-level environment variables."

Comment: Yes, plus I had forgotten about actually already having defined the variable. However, I would still expect `phpunit` to honour its own `phpunit.xml`. Plus there's some discrepancy (at least that's how I see it) regarding Laravel "automatically setting the configuration environment to `testing` [...]". Thank you for your continued interest in helping out.